# Return 0 if count(*) is null and associated date for that count

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
    SELECT DATE(leads_update_on), IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) leads 
    FROM tbl_leads 
    WHERE project_id=4 
    AND DATE(leads_update_on) >= DATE_SUB('2016-05-11', INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
    GROUP BY DATE(leads_update_on)
```

`

Currently I have records for `2016-05-06`and`2016-05-07` only and above query returns me result like

```
           `DATE(leads_update_on)|leads
           ----------------------|-----
           2016-05-06            |    7
           2016-05-07            |    4`
```

But I expect result like

```
           `DATE(leads_update_on)|leads
           ----------------------|-----
           2016-05-05            |    0
           2016-05-06            |    7
           2016-05-07            |    4
           2016-05-08            |    0
           2016-05-09            |    0
           2016-05-10            |    0
           2016-05-11            |    0`
```

Here `DATE_SUB('**2016-05-11**', INTERVAL **6** DAY)` is dynamic and depends on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a database, to get the dates you have to have the dates in a row; since you don't have them all, you have to generate them first. This will generate a list of 1000 days before your input date and join them with your query:

```
select DateBase.BaseDate, ifnull(l.leads, 0) as leads
from (
    SELECT DATE(leads_update_on) as leads_update_on, COUNT(*) as leads 
    FROM tbl_leads 
    WHERE project_id=4 
    AND DATE(leads_update_on) >= DATE_SUB('2016-05-11', INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
    GROUP BY DATE(leads_update_on)
) l
right outer join 
(   SELECT
    DATE_SUB('2016-05-11', 
    INTERVAL INTPART1.n + INTPART2.n * 10 + INTPART3.n * 100 day) as BaseDate
FROM
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
     union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) INTPART1
    cross join  
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
     union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) INTPART2
    cross join  
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
     union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) INTPART3
where INTPART1.n + INTPART2.n * 10 + INTPART3.n * 100 <= 6
) as DateBase
on l.leads_update_on = DateBase.BaseDate;
```

You have to put the two inputvalues `6` and `2016-05-11` in.

It will "only" generate 1000 days, if there is any possibility you need more, you have to add another join (if you only need 100 you can get rid of one join). If you need that query often, you can generate an integerbasetable with just integers from e.g. 0 to 1000 so you don't have to generate it every time.

The result will just include the days until, in your example, `2016-05-11`. If you had an entry for `2016-05-15` in your table, your query would include it, since you have no upper boundary. But your example output had an upper bound depending on the input date, so I assumed you meant to have that and my query will not include `2016-05-15`. Otherwise, you have to set the date in `SELECT DATE_SUB('2016-05-11', INTERVAL INTPART1.n ...` to the highest date in your database. (e.g. replace the date by `(select max(leads_update_on) from tlb_leads)`) or specify what you need exactly.